# Laravel - custom error page redirect

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

I have a really strange issue with custom error pages in Laravel. I have this code in the global.php file

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    if (!Config::get('app.debug'))
    {
        switch ($code)
        {
            case 403:
                return Redirect::route('error', array($code));
            case 404:
                return Redirect::route('error', array($code));
            case 500:
                return Redirect::route('error', array($code));
            default:
            return Redirect::route('error', array($code));
        }
    }

});
```

Very simple code that just redirects to a route on specific error codes if the debug flag in the config is false. And this works just fine on my localhost, but on the web server I get the Apache error of 404 not found

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /error/404 was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at domain.com Port 80

What is the problem here, do I need to run something on the web server so Laravel recognizes this routes, what is happening here?

Apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/_dev/websites/dev3/public
    ServerName dev3.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ErrorLog logs/dev3.com-error.log
    CustomLog logs/dev3.com-access.log common
    <IfModule php5_module>
      php_value newrelic.appname "web02-dev3.com"
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: do you have routes for /error/{code} configured ?

Comment: @disf.asia yes they are, it works in my localhost

Comment: @watcher the are the same for now, latter it will have a custom page for each error code

Comment: what about the other routes? do they work ? It could be an apache misconfiguration. check if local and remote are configured in the same way (especially mod_rewrite enabled)

Comment: @disf.asia yes they do work, forgot to mention all other routes work on localhost and on the web server, just this one route is not working on the web server

Comment: it could be some apache default configuration, like `Location /error/` or something like that.

Comment: @disf.asia added the apache config in the question

Comment: @VladimirSabo that one is the virtual host config, i was looking for something inside apache2.conf file, the main one

Comment: try also to check the /var/log/apache2/error.log file to see what it says

Comment: @disf.asia no errors in apache error log file